# Replace the image on radio button

Tags: c#, image, radio-button, uwp, uwp-xaml

How do I replace the image on radio button?
I want to use the image below for each of its radio button.

[image: radio button image]

XAML:

```
 <RadioButton x:Name="FreshBtn" Content="Fresh" Style="{StaticResource TabRadioButtonStyle}" IsChecked="True" Click="FreshBtn_Click" FontSize="23" Grid.Column="0"/>
 <RadioButton x:Name="PopularBtn" Content="Popular" Style="{StaticResource TabRadioButtonStyle}" IsChecked="False" Margin="0,0,0,0" Click="PopularBtn_Click" FontSize="23" Grid.Column="1"/>
 <RadioButton x:Name="FreeBtn" Content="Free" Style="{StaticResource TabRadioButtonStyle}" IsChecked="False" Margin="0,0,0,0" Click="FreeBtn_Click" FontSize="23" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

And I also want to ask how to change the image on the radio button when clicked?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to change the background picture of the radio button. For that you can do as follows:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="FreshBtn" Content="" Style="{StaticResource TabRadioButtonStyle}" IsChecked="True" Click="FreshBtn_Click" FontSize="23" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,302,0,301" Checked="FreshBtn_Checked">
    <RadioButton.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/myImage.jpg"></ImageBrush>
    </RadioButton.Background>
</RadioButton>
```

For changing the back ground when the radio button is clicked you will need to impelement a Clicked or Changed event handler. The following is an example of the clicked one, that will change the background on clicking the radio button:

```
private void FreshBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FreshBtn.Background = new ImageBrush
    {
        Stretch = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill,
        ImageSource =
            new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/myImage_2.png") }
    };
}
```

In order to change the picture when the radio button is clicked you still need to implement a "Clicked" event handler so that when the radio button is clicked the image is changed, the code above should work with that.

Comment: My point is how if the radio button is selected then the picture will change? And  how to remove the circle on radio button (circle on the left side of the button)?

Comment: That also works the same way as above. You will still need to implement an event handler for your radio button.

Comment: Also in your question you never mentioned anything about removing a circle of any kind....I am not sure what you mean by "how to remove the circle on radio button (circle on the left side of the button)" maybe being more clear in the question and adding a picture would help clarify.

Comment: I mean when the radio button is selected then the picture will change and when the radio button is selected, then the picture will return to its original image. How?
I want to get rid of the circle on the left images (like a picture that I put a red circle https://1drv.ms/i/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U7TvB-0oW6SVKyJy1) so as shown tab button. How do I apply?

Comment: For that you will need to write a Control template as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/control-templates)